# Why a NullPointer Exception from adding to a Collection?

Tags: java, collections, nullpointerexception

I am doing some experimentation on why I'm getting a NullPointerException when I try to add an object to a List. Below is my code, and the StackTrace. Do you know why I'm getting a NullPointerException when I try to add an object to a List?

This is my test class.

```
package com.greathouse.aggregationtest;

import com.greathouse.aggregationtest.types.Composite;
import com.greathouse.aggregationtest.types.InitializedComponent;
import com.greathouse.aggregationtest.types.NullComponent;
import com.greathouse.aggregationtest.types.NullContainingComponent;

public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        System.out.println( "Testing aggregation" );

        InitializedComponent initializedComponent1 = new InitializedComponent();
        initializedComponent1.setInitializedString("Test Initialization 1 Successful");

        InitializedComponent initializedComponent2 = new InitializedComponent();
        initializedComponent2.setInitializedString("Test Initialization 2 Successful");

        NullComponent nullComponent1 = null;
        NullComponent nullComponent2 = null;

        NullContainingComponent nulLContainingComponent1 = new NullContainingComponent();
        nulLContainingComponent1.setIntendedNullString(null);

        NullContainingComponent nullContainingComponent2 = new NullContainingComponent();
        nullContainingComponent2.setIntendedNullString(null);

        System.out.println(initializedComponent1.getInitializedString());
        System.out.println(initializedComponent2.getInitializedString());
        System.out.println(nullComponent1);
        System.out.println(nullComponent2);
        System.out.println(nulLContainingComponent1.getIntendedNullString());
        System.out.println(nullContainingComponent2.getIntendedNullString());

        Composite composite = new Composite();
        composite.addInitializedComponents(initializedComponent1);
        composite.addInitializedComponents(initializedComponent2);
        composite.addNullComponent(nullComponent1);
        composite.addNullComponent(nullComponent2);
        composite.addNullContainingComponent(nulLContainingComponent1);
        composite.addNullContainingComponent(nullContainingComponent2);
    }
}
```

This is the Composite object. The component object are simple wrappers with accessors.

```
package com.greathouse.aggregationtest.types;

import java.util.List;

public class Composite {
    private List<InitializedComponent> initializedComponents;
    private List<NullComponent> nullcomponents;
    private List<NullContainingComponent> nullContainingComponents;
    /**
     * @return the initializedComponents
     */
    public List<InitializedComponent> getInitializedComponents() {
        return initializedComponents;
    }
    /**
     * @return the nullComponents
     */
    public List<NullComponent> getNullcomponents() {
        return nullcomponents;
    }
    /**
     * @return the nullContainingComponents
     */
    public List<NullContainingComponent> getNullContainingComponents() {
        return nullContainingComponents;
    }
    public void addInitializedComponents(InitializedComponent initializedComponent) {
    this.initializedComponents.add(initializedComponent);
    }
    public void addNullComponent(NullComponent nullcomponent) {
    this.nullcomponents.add(nullcomponent);
    }
    public void addNullContainingComponent(NullContainingComponent nullContainingComponent) {
    this.nullContainingComponents.add(nullContainingComponent);
    }
}
```

The console output.

```
Testing aggregation
Test Initialization 1 Successful
Test Initialization 2 Successful
null
null
null
null
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.greathouse.aggregationtest.types.Composite.addInitializedComponents(Composite.java:28)
at com.greathouse.aggregationtest.App.main(App.java:41)
```

Comment: On what line is the null reference exception thrown?

Comment: And the stacktrace?, where do you initialize the attributes in Composite?

Comment: Look over to the related questions on the right. NullPointerExceptions are not exactly uncommon questions. Please search and read.

Comment: I agree with the others. It seems you didn't do your homework... Also, if there is a line number in the stack trace - let us know where it is pointing at! E.g. make a code comment like `// <-- NPE thrown here (Line 28)`.

Comment: I searched, none of the others I found were addressing Collections. In addition, I felt that the error, "..addInitializedComponents.." gave a pretty good indication of where the error was coming from. How about instead of naysaying, you just help. Like the folks that actually answered the question.

Comment: @cyotee, that is simply **not** how this site is supposed to work. We are **not** here to hand you solutions on a silver platter. You **must do your own research** and **your question is clearly answered** on this site already. If you searched "NullPointerException list" (just for example) you could not possibly miss plenty of applicable duplicates.

Comment: Then point out the original question that would have answered my question. Because obviously I didn't find one that helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `InitializedComponent`'s `List` is not initialized. :)

```
private List<InitializedComponent> initializedComponents =
                                   new ArrayList<InitializedComponent>();
```

Your `NullComponent`'s List is also `NULL`. You need to instantiate all your member field `List`s before trying to add an element to them.

```
private List<NullComponent> nullcomponents =
                            new ArrayList<NullComponent>();
private List<NullContainingComponent> nullContainingComponents =
                                      new ArrayList<NullContainingComponent>();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
  private List<InitializedComponent> initializedComponents;
  private List<NullComponent> nullcomponents;
  private List<NullContainingComponent> nullContainingComponents;
```

This attributes are not initialized

You created an instance of `Composite` but you never defined a constructor to initialize these attributes...

You can try this in Composite:

```
public Composite()
{
     this.initializedComponents = new ArrayList<InitializedComponent>();
     this.nullcomponents = new ArrayList<NullComponent>();
     this.nullContainingComponents = new ArrayList<NullContainingComponent>();
}
```

Comment: Also that List<T> may or may not support null values. List<NullComponent> nullcomponents as ArrayList would support.